# Como extraer solo las tablas de un correo de outlook con macros

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Buenas días con todos y de antemano gracias por su apoyo, tengo una macro que extrae los correos de outlook y los pone a modo de tabla, pero estoy buscando solo extraer tablas dentro del correo en el body. es decir si en un correo hay una tabla con 3 columnas y n filas solo extraer esa tabla, tengo un código de ejemplo que puede funcionar pero no se como adaptarlo, adjunto.

Macro que permite extraer correos:

````
Sub ExtraerCorreosDeOutlook()





Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim ONameSpace As Object
Dim MyFolder As Object
Dim OItem As Object
Dim Fila As Integer





Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ONameSpace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set MyFolder = ONameSpace.Folders("xxxxxx").Folders("Bandeja de Entrada").Folders("aaaaaa").Folders("bbbbbb")





Range(Range("A2"), ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).ClearContents





Fila = 2





For Each OItem In MyFolder.Items



   
    Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(Fila, 1).Value = OItem.SenderEmailAddress
    Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(Fila, 2).Value = OItem.To
    Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(Fila, 3).Value = OItem.Subject
    Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(Fila, 4).Value = OItem.ReceivedTime
    Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(Fila, 5).Value = OItem.Body





  Fila = Fila + 1





Next OItem





Set OutlookApp = Nothing
Set ONameSpace = Nothing
Set MyFolder = Nothing



End Sub ```
````

Y el código para extraer tablas es el siguiente:

```
Dim item As MailItem, x%
Dim r As Object 'As Word.Range
Dim doc As Object 'As Word.Document
Dim xlApp As Object, wkb As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\dwh\File.xlsx")
xlApp.Visible = True









Dim wks As Object
Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)









For Each item In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
Set doc = item.GetInspector.WordEditor
For x = 1 To doc.Tables.Count
Set r = doc.Tables(x)
r.Range.Copy
wks.Paste
wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Offset(1).Select
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Por favor quiero ver como podría juntar esto?

Comment: Hola. El ejemplo que colocas y que crees que se podría adaptar, pues no te será útil dado que las tablas en los cuerpos de mensajes de Outlook se basan en etiquetas, no en objetos Table.

Comment: Hola Abraham! gracias por responder. Comentarte que el segundo codigo que muestro se basa en una macro funciona dentro de outlook que extrae las tablas dentro de un cuerpo de un correo, pero en todo caso, como lo podria hacer?

Comment: Tu `OItem` debe ser un `MailItem` (`If Not (OItem Is MailItem): GoTo error`) Entonces  `OItem`  funciona igual que tu `item` de tu segundo código. Por tanto, si tu pones `Set doc = OItem.GetInspector.WordEditor` debes poder recuperar el código.